# Is it possible to add noise around(edge perimeter) a low poly object after adding texture?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, shaders

Still grasping at nodes and its possibilities, but is possible to add noise around(edge perimeter) to a low poly object after adding texture?
I've managed to add texture for the surface, but the edges of object is still smooth and flat.
Should I go back and add and tweak geometry/subdivide to the model for desired edge roughness?
(BTW subdivision modifier is yet to be applied- if that has any significance)
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the material setting enable *Displacement and Bump* to start affecting the underlying mesh.  Higher subdivision means more vertices to work with.  *Adaptive Subdivision* is something to look into.

[image]

Be aware, last time I used *Ambient Occlusion* to drive *Displacement* in any way, I was having some funky dependency issues.  Seems pretty finicky to me.

You also have your scale set to 10, so the initial results may be hilarious, and need scaled down.

Comment: I saw immediate differences after the option was toggled for both displacement and map. I also opt of the ambient occlusion until I learn nodes better. This forum is priceless- but thats not to say I wont continue to educate myself before running here with every problem =). Thanks for your time and lesson learned.